# Counting the frequency of words in python

Tags: python, count, cpu-word

I am trying to remove the punctuation and count the frequency of 
    words.Part of my code works but my codes seems incomplete.

```
def word_distribution(text_string):    
words_list = text_string.split()
words_list = [words_list[i].lower() for i in range(len(words_list))]

for i in range(len(words_list)):
    if not words_list[i].isalpha():
        word = words_list[i]
        for j in word:
            if j != "\'" and  not j.isalpha():
                id = word.find(j)
                words_list[i] = word.replace(word[id],"")

words_dict = {}
for word in words_list:
    if word in words_dict:
        words_dict[word] += 1
    else:
        words_dict[word] = 1    
result = words_dict
return result

word_distribution("Hello,, hello, hi, Hurray!!!, Hurray,  What's up!,Today 
 is Saturday, Saturday, saturday. Funday.")
```

I am trying to get a dict of words like {'hello': 2,'hi': 1} and so on. It works for hello word but for Hurray its giving me an output like hurray!!!': 1,'hurray': 1 instead of Hurray:2. I could't figure out why its acting like that.

Any inputs on why its acting like that is appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation is off. Can you fix it.

Comment: Why don't you convert the text to lower case before you split it rather than looping through converting each individual word to lower case? And to do it your way: `word_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]`

Comment: That should be: `words_list = [word.lower() for word in words_list]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for splitting the sentence with non-alpha characters. and can get the result

````py
import re

def word_distribution(s):
    res = re.split(r'\W+', s)
    counter = {}
    for word in res:
        if not counter.get(word):
            counter[word] = 1
        else:
            counter[word] += 1
    return counter
s = "Hello,, hello, hi, Hurray!!!, Hurray,  What's up!,Today is Saturday, Saturday, saturday. Funday."
print(word_distribution(s))```
#Output:
#{'Hello': 1, 'hello': 1, 'hi': 1, 'Hurray': 2, 'What': 1, 's': 1, 'up': 1, 'Today': 1, 'is': 1, 'Saturday': 2, 'saturday': 1, 'Funday': 1, '': 1}
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_distribution(text_string):
    regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
    return Counter(regex.sub('', word.lower()) for word in text_string.split())


s = "Hello,, hello, hi, Hurray!!!, Hurray,  What's up!,Today is Saturday, Saturday, saturday. Funday."

print(word_distribution(s)) #Counter({'saturday': 3, 'hello': 2, 'hurray': 2, 'whats': 1, 'funday': 1, 'is': 1, 'hi': 1, 'uptoday': 1})
```